# Using a DB context factory in Blazor server

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, dbcontext

I'm having a few issues setting up the EF database connection for my server side Blazor app. It was working with the standard `DbContext` setup until I noticed a few issues with connections not closing properly due to the nature of Blazor using the same context throughout. My research led me to look at `DbContextFactory`, but the interface `IDbContextFactory` is now deprecated in favour of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`.

I've set up a class to implement the interface:

```
public class FIS2ContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<FIS2_DbContext>
{
    private readonly DbContextOptions<FIS2_FranklinContext_AutoGenerated> options;

    public FIS2ContextFactory(DbContextOptions<FIS2_FranklinContext_AutoGenerated> contextOptions)
    {
        options = contextOptions;
    }

    public FIS2_DbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        return new FIS2_DbContext(options);
    }
}
```

The DbContext I'm wanting to use is this, which inherits and expands on the DbContext generated by EF Power Tools:

```
public partial class FIS2_DbContext : FIS2_FranklinContext_AutoGenerated
{
    public FIS2_DbContext()
    {
    }

    public FIS2_DbContext(DbContextOptions<FIS2_FranklinContext_AutoGenerated> options) : base(options)

    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<StudentBasicDetailsWithCurrentTg> StudentBasicDetailsWithCurrentTgs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CurriculumSearchBasicDetails> CurriculumSearchBasicDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<StudentAllEnrolments> StudentAllEnrolments { get; set; }
}
```

In my `startup.cs` I have it set up like this in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextFactory<FIS2_DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FIS2")));

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddScoped<IFileService, FileService>();
        services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>();
        services.AddScoped<ITimetableService, TimetableService>();
        services.AddScoped<ICurriculumService, CurriculumServiceEf>();
        services.AddScoped<IStudentService, StudentServiceEf>();
        services.AddScoped<ICollectionService, CollectionsServiceEf>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddAuthenticationCore();
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();
        services.AddScoped<SessionState>();
    }
```

My issue is that when it gets to setting up the services that utilise this database connection, I am met with this error message in the `program.cs`:

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DataLibrary.Data.Interfaces.ITimetableService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: DataLibrary.Data.BusinessLayer.TimetableService': Unable to resolve service for type 'DataLibrary.Models.FIS2ContextFactory' while attempting to activate 'DataLibrary.Data.BusinessLayer.TimetableService'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DataLibrary.Data.Interfaces.ICurriculumService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: DataLibrary.Data.BusinessLayer.CurriculumServiceEf': Unable to resolve service for type 'DataLibrary.Models.FIS2ContextFactory' while attempting to activate 'DataLibrary.Data.BusinessLayer.CurriculumServiceEf'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DataLibrary.Data.Interfaces.IStudentService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: DataLibrary.Data.BusinessLayer.StudentServiceEf': Unable to resolve service for type 'DataLibrary.Models.FIS2ContextFactory' while attempting to activate 'DataLibrary.Data.BusinessLayer.StudentServiceEf'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DataLibrary.Data.Interfaces.ICollectionService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: DataLibrary.Data.BusinessLayer.CollectionsServiceEf': Unable to resolve service for type 'DataLibrary.Models.FIS2ContextFactory' while attempting to activate 'DataLibrary.Data.BusinessLayer.CollectionsServiceEf'.)

For reference, here is an example of how the `TimetableService` is set up (the others are instantiated in the same way):

```
using DataLibrary.Data.Interfaces;
using DataLibrary.Models;
using DataLibrary.Models.timetable;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataLibrary.Data.BusinessLayer
{
    public class TimetableService : ITimetableService
    {
        private FIS2ContextFactory _contextFactory;

        public TimetableService(FIS2ContextFactory db)
        {
            _contextFactory = db;
        }

        public async Task<List<spGetHolidaysBetweenDatesResult>> GetHolidaysBetweenDatesAsync(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            string[] args = { "" };
            var _db = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext(args);
            var procedures = _db.Procedures;

            return await procedures.spGetHolidaysBetweenDatesAsync(startDate, endDate);
        }

        public async Task<List<PeriodsBetweenDates>> GetPeriodsBetweenDatesAsync(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            string[] args = { "" };
            var _db = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext(args);
            var procedures = _db.Procedures;
            var toReturn = new List<PeriodsBetweenDates>();
            var results = await procedures.spGetPeriodsBetweenDatesAsync(startDate, endDate);
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                toReturn.Add(new PeriodsBetweenDates(item.Date, item.Timetable, item.BlockCode, item.StartTime, item.EndTime));
            }
            return toReturn;
        }

        public async Task<List<StudentTimetable>> GetStudentTimetableAsync(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string studentID)
        {
            string[] args = { "" };
            var _db = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext(args);
            var procedures = _db.Procedures;
            var results = await procedures.spGetStudentTimetableAsync(startDate, endDate, studentID);

            List<StudentTimetable> studentTimetables = new List<StudentTimetable>();
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                studentTimetables.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StudentTimetable>(item.timetable));
            }
            return studentTimetables;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it because I'm using the wrong method to create the context factory in the startup, or is it something later on that I've got wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to resolve a specific factory type, you must register with this overload, `AddDbContextFactory<TContext,TFactory>` documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontextfactory?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions_AddDbContextFactory__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_System_IServiceProvider_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder__Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_):

> This overload allows a specific implementation of
> IDbContextFactory to be registered instead of using the
> default factory shipped with EF Core.

so

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<FIS2_DbContext,FIS2ContextFactory>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FIS2")));
```

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't spotted that with it being squirrelled away in the DI area as opposed to the class/interface specific block elsewhere. 

Although, doing it that way it doesn't like the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` implementation so I've reverted to the `IDbContextFactory`